# How to add Global secondary index to the existing table in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the table in DynamoDB and need to update the schema with the new field, to scan on it later. How can I update the table with GSI (in java code)? Sorry, I am a newbie with AWS and found out only the way of adding CSI only while table creation in documentation.

Comment: did you try doing it from aws console?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSIJavaDocumentAPI.html

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/create-update-and-delete-global-secondary-indexes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-api/